# Apply css on RestFul Spring MVC

Tags: css, spring-mvc, restful-url

This would be not a very relevant question but I couldn't explain how Spring handle CSS resources. I am trying to build a RestFul web service. So I have  multiple url which will map to 1 page:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dashboard", method=RequestMethod.GET )
public String showdashboardPage() {
    return "dashboard";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/dashboard/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showDashboardInstance(@PathVariable(value="id") int id) {
    return "dashboard";
}
```

There is no problem with showdashboardPage(). The css display nicely. But when I try to call showDashboardInstance(), the page still display its content but the css is lost. I tried to fix it by adding @Responsebody or changed the return type but none will solve it. I tried to search but couldn't find any hint. I need help! SOS!!!

Comment: You can check in network tab of your browser,what is the URL for the css in second request?

Comment: How do you include the CSS file in your page? I guess it's relative to the page's URL.